# Minolta XE-7 shooting Ilford Delta 400 B&W 35mm. Film came out clear, save for about 5 decent exposures

Tags: film, troubleshooting, 35mm, developing, minolta

I just bought a Minolta xe-7, shot my first roll and developed it at home. The result was a roll of film that came out almost completely clear except for the fist several exposures on the roll and a few white spots here and there.

The film does have edge markings on it which seems to indicate that the development process went ok, and everything I can find on this points to a camera issue.

However I tested the camera before and after loading the film and the shutter opens and closes just fine, and I had no problems advancing the film while I was shooting. The safe load indicator moved as it should and the frame counter advanced properly and stopped once i got to the end of the roll.

So far I cannot find a satisfactory answer so I'm hoping someone here can help me out. Thanks!

[image: spot on negative]

[image: spot on negative]

[image: First several exposures]
[image: decent exposure at the start of roll]

Comment: And, did the camera make the same _sound_ when you shot the blank frames as it made when you shot the "first several" frames? Also, "...white spots?" Were those "white spots" in the "first several?" or were they in the "almost completely clear" part of the roll? Maybe you could add a picture of a few of those white spots to the question.

Comment: Did you set the **ASA dial to 400** ? Did you shoot in auto or manual ? if manual did you take a **meter reading and set the fstop  accordingly** ?

Comment: Minolta XE-7 SLR – Camera Review   https://casualphotophile.com/2014/04/14/minolta-xe-7-slr-a-casual-retrospective/

Comment: To clarify, the white spots were on the clear part of the roll, as if only those spots got any exposure. I'll add a few pictures when I get home. Also, yes the dial was set to ASA 400, and I was switching from manual to auto to familiarize myself with the camera, but making sure to change settings with the meter readings when on manual. As far as I can tell the camera made the same sound throughout the whole roll.

Comment: When you said "White spots" were you actually talking about _dark_ spots on a negative that would print as white if you chose to print it? Seriously! post a _picture_ of the film and _show_ us what you're talking about.

Comment: I added pictures as I promised. The first couple are of those spots I was talking about (My guess is the spots are just artifacts from developing). The next one is of my first 12 or so frames where I got some decent exposures (although most turned out like garbage) and the last pic is one of the few decent shots I could salvage. I can't find this exact issue anywhere else- where the camera takes some shots and then suddenly stops mid-roll. My guess is that the shutter only works intermittently for some reason, but I thought I'd ask someone with more experience

Comment: Re. the spots: it looks like the film has stuck to itself when in the tank, inhibiting normal flow of the chemicals over the film surface. Are you sure it was correctly loaded onto the reel? Did you feel any resistance when loading it? Re. the shutter: have you tried firing it on different speeds without film, observing how the curtains behave? That should be enough to diagnose whether there's a problem with the shutter.

Comment: I think you're right about the spots, this was my first time developing and I had a little trouble getting it on the reel in the pitch black. And I just checked the shutter again and  I noticed that it will fire intermittently when the speed is set to 1000. Which is the setting I was using for most of the roll. Curiously enough it'll fire at 1000 when on auto but only intermittently on manual. I just contacted the local repair place so hopefully I can get that fixed soon. Thanks everybody for your help

Comment: @Kahovius [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871) and [Criteria for determining if a post should be a comment or an answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5578/15871)